# Specflow NUnit BDD framework

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I had install VS for MAC , Also install specflow from Nuget package , but while creating new solution I did not find option to add specflow feature file etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is still a product in preview, and so many pieces are missing. If possible, you can extend it (like any other MonoDevelop addins).